# How to display posts categori list by day wordpres

Tags: date

**Please help me**

I want to make a list based on the name of the day ordered
based on the selected category

I have code like this but it doesn't work **orderby day**

```
<?php


$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'offset'=> 0, 
'category' => 338,'order'=> 'asc', 'orderby' => 'day');



$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<tr>
<td><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
<td><?php the_time('l'); ?></td>
<td><?php the_time('H:i'); ?> Wib</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

1 week is equal to 7 days
**how to make wordpres code sorted by day. ?**

Answer (score 0):

There is a better method using **date_query** property of WP_Query class:

```
'date_query'    => array(
        'column'  => 'post_date',
        'after'   => '- 1 days'
)
```